# Subclass of Subclass of NSmanagedobject

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I want to add some business logic of a class "person" which is a subclass of NSmanagedObject

> Is Categories is the only option to Implement the Business logic of a sublass of NSmanagedobject ?

because I don't want to implement business logic into the same class which is a subclass of NSManagedObject class

Looking forward for you participation

thanks,

Comment: You need to rephrase this question - it doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 ways people usually deal with this problem.

1st is to add categories to particular models and have the logic there

2nd is to use https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator tool.

Second option requires a little bit of setup but otherwise is a better way to go.

hope it helps.

Comment: is there any other technique so that we don't have to use mogenerator ?

Comment: Using mogenerator is the best solution. You could just do it by hand, but it would be a lot more awkward.